# Throughput and Transfer time of a network

Tags: networking, transfer, throughput

A big file will be sent from A host to B host through 3 links with the speed of 500 Kbps, 2Mbps, and 1Mbps.

**a)** assume that there is just one user on the system , what is the end-to-end throughput?

**b)** if file is 4gb , how long the transfer will last?

**c)** answer the a and b options again thinking there is 100Kbps link instead of 2Mbps link.

Comment: What answers did you put and why?

Comment: a) 2mbps because it is the fastest one.  b) i calculated according to the 4gb link.   c) a is 1mbps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The throughput will be the speed of the slowest link as that forms a bottleneck - you can do the calculation for yourself.